# Scanning a newline using fgets from a .txt file in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a text file (fruits.txt), which looks something like this:

```
apple chloe
banana ben james
grape chloe james
kiwi ben chloe james
orange ben james
pear ben
```

I want to order all of this text into something like

```
ben: banana kiwi pear
chloe: apple grape kiwi orange
james: banana grape kiwi orange
```

in a C program.

What I was originally thinking was using `fgets()`, `sscanf()` or `fscanf()`, but I ran into quite a few problems because not all of the lines in fruits.txt has the same amount of words, which resulted in making a fixed scanning format

`(such as fscanf("%s %s %s", name, fruit1, fruit2))`

impossible, thus requiring me to scan a newline from fruits.txt.
However, I cannot think of a way to code this because it seemed like scanning in a string with %s does not include a newline.

Can someone help me out through this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the line using `fgets`. Split it it at white-space (with e.g. `strtok`). The first string is the fruit, all the others are the names, which you need to store in a suitable data-structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an exercise for myself I implemented what you're looking for.

You should adjust the array sizes as required. It just prints the output to `stdout` but of course you can change this to write to file that's what you need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PEOPLE    10
#define MAX_FRUIT     10
#define MAX_LINE_LEN  120
#define MAX_TOKEN_LEN 10
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char person[MAX_PEOPLE][MAX_TOKEN_LEN] = {};
    char fruit[MAX_FRUIT][MAX_TOKEN_LEN] = {};
    int personFruit[MAX_PEOPLE][MAX_FRUIT] = {0};
    int numFruit = 0;
    int numPeople = 0;
    
    // Open file in reading mode
    fp = fopen("fruits.txt", "r");
    if (NULL == fp) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
        return 0;
    }
 
    // Process input file line by line
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fp) != NULL) {

            int nToken = 0, nFruitIndex = 0;
            char* token = strtok(line, " ");
            while (token != NULL) {

                // Trim trailing line-feed if present
                if (token[strlen(token) - 1] == '\n')
                    token[strlen(token) - 1] = '\0';

                // Add first token to fruit array
                if (nToken++ == 0) {
                    nFruitIndex = numFruit;
                    strcpy(fruit[numFruit++], token);
                }
                else {
                    // Process people tokens on line 
                    // Is this a new person or someone already encountered?
                    int nPersonIndex = 0, bFoundPerson = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
                        if (strcmp(token, person[i]) == 0) {
                            nPersonIndex = i;
                            bFoundPerson = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!bFoundPerson) {
                        nPersonIndex = numPeople;
                        strcpy(person[numPeople++], token);
                    }
                    personFruit[nPersonIndex][nFruitIndex]++;
                }

                // Get next token
                token = strtok(NULL,  " ");
            }
    }

    // Print output - list fruit each person has
    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
        printf("%s:", person[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < numFruit; j++)
            if (personFruit[i][j] > 0)
                printf(" %s", fruit[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Close file
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```